# Display Wifi list in React Native

Tags: react-native

I need to display available WiFi network's list.
By using `npm install react-native-wifi-reborn --save` I can get the list but only in the log. How can I display the Wifi List as text from the console log.

I tried this  code.

[image]

But got this error
`Error: Exception in HostFunction: Malformed calls from JS: field sizes are different.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the docs,`loadWifiList()` returns `Promise<Array<WifiEntry>>`, so you should either use `async/await` or `.then` to access the result.
You could try something like this

```
const getWifiList = async() => {
    let wifiList = await wifi.loadWifiList(); //wifiList will be Array<WifiEntry>
    console.log('wifi list',wifiList);  
}
```